# Denormalizing MLData in Encog

Tags: encog

I have Normalized a set of data using the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

//To Normalize the data
    File sourcefiletotrain=new File("E:\\Shreyas-Internship\\RforLF\\dataforAnn.csv");
    File targetfiletotrain=new File("E:\\Shreyas-Internship\\RforLF\\ideal.csv");
    EncogAnalyst analyst=new EncogAnalyst();
    AnalystWizard wizard=new AnalystWizard(analyst);
    wizard.setGoal(AnalystGoal.Regression);
    wizard.wizard(sourcefiletotrain, false,AnalystFileFormat.DECPNT_COMMA);
    final AnalystNormalizeCSV norm=new AnalystNormalizeCSV();
    norm.analyze(sourcefiletotrain, false, ENGLISH, analyst);
    norm.normalize(targetfiletotrain);
```

Then I have used the following data to train and run the neural network using Encog. The problem i am facing is that I am unable to denormalize the value back to actual form. The code for training and running the neural network is:

```
  //To Train the Neural Network
    CSVNeuralDataSet fileread=new CSVNeuralDataSet("E:\\Shreyas-Internship\\RforLF\\ideal.csv",4,1,true);
    BasicNetwork network=new BasicNetwork();
    network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(4));
    network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(20));
    network.addLayer(new BasicLayer(1));
    network.getStructure().finalizeStructure();
    network.reset();
    MLDataSet trainingset=new BasicMLDataSet(fileread);
    MLTrain train= new ResilientPropagation(network,trainingset);
    int epoch=1;
    do{

        train.iteration();
        System.out.println("Epoch " +epoch+ " Error:" +train.getError());
        epoch++;
       }while((train.getError()>0.01)&&(epoch<=500));



    //To run the Neural Network
    System.out.println("Neural Network Results");
    for (MLDataPair pair: trainingset){  
        final MLData output=network.compute(pair.getInput());  
        System.out.println("actual="+output.getData(0)+  "\tideal="+pair.getIdeal().getData(0));//pair.getInput().getData(0)+" ,"+pair.getInput().getData(1)+" ,"+pair.getInput().getData(2)+" ,"+pair.getInput().getData(3)+" ,"+pair.getInput().getData(4)+" ,"+pair.getInput().getData(5)+


    }


}
```

The doubt is how do i further proceed to obtain the denormalized output for the MLData

Comment: Also if an alternative is available in Encog to normalize, train, run and denormalise a set of data, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use encog [NormalizedField](http://heatonresearch-site.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/javadoc/encog-3.3/org/encog/util/arrayutil/NormalizedField.html) class:

```
def denormalize(double high, double low, double normalizedValue){
    NormalizedField normalizedField = new NormalizedField(high, low)
    normalizedField.deNormalize(normalizedValue)
}
```

where **high** and **low** is a range used for a normalization.